# Comparing data from two rows in a same sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to find out differences between two rows in a same table. Having trouble to find right query. For example, I have

```
Year   Item      Qty    Amount 
------------------------------
2014   Shoes     500     2500 
2014   Ties      300      900 
2014   Pants     200     4000 
2015   Shoes     600     3000 
2015   Ties      200      600
```

I am trying to find out what was the increased (or decreased) from previous year to this year. I will always have only two years to compare. The query result should look like following:

```
Items   Qty Diff   Amount Diff 
------------------------------
Shoes      100         500 
Ties    (-100)      (-300) 
Pants     Null        Null
```

What should be the query look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Use LAG or LEAD**

```
WITH tb(Year,Item,Qty,Amount) AS (
     SELECT 2014,'Shoes',500,2500 UNION
     SELECT 2014,'Ties',300,900 UNION
     SELECT 2014,'Pants',200,4000 UNION
     SELECT 2015,'Shoes',600,3000 UNION
     SELECT 2015,'Ties',200,600
 ) 
 SELECT *,Qty-LAG(qty)OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY year) AS QtyDiff ,Amount-LAG(Amount)OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY year) AS AmountDiff 
 FROM tb
```

```
Year        Item  Qty         Amount      QtyDiff     AmountDiff
----------- ----- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2014        Pants 200         4000        NULL        NULL
2014        Shoes 500         2500        NULL        NULL
2015        Shoes 600         3000        100         500
2014        Ties  300         900         NULL        NULL
2015        Ties  200         600         -100        -300
```

**2.Cross or Outer Apply**

```
WITH tb(Year,Item,Qty,Amount) AS (
     SELECT 2014,'Shoes',500,2500 UNION
     SELECT 2014,'Ties',300,900 UNION
     SELECT 2014,'Pants',200,4000 UNION
     SELECT 2015,'Shoes',600,3000 UNION
     SELECT 2015,'Ties',200,600
 ) 
 SELECT t1.Year,t1.Item,t1.Qty- t2.qty AS DiffQty,t1.Amount-t2.Amount AS DiffAmount
 FROM tb AS t1
 OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 tt.qty,tt.Amount FROM tb AS tt WHERE tt.Year<t1.Year AND t1.Item=tt.Item ORDER BY tt.Year desc) AS t2
 ORDER BY t1.Item,t1.Year
```

Comment: Impressive and thank you! I assume some came as null since nothing to compare with previous year ( Method 1). Is there anyway I can get rid of those and get only the item name only? Thank you again

Answer (score 5):

If you want to include everything, then you can use `FULL OUTER JOIN`, if just the one with the earlier year, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, if you want the one with both earlier and subsequent year, then `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT
    T1.Item
    , (T2.QTY-T1.QTY) AS [QTY Diff]
    , (T2.Amount - T1.Amount) AS [Amount Diff]
FROM
    <<Table>> T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN <<Table>> T2
        ON T1.Item=T2.Item
        AND T1.YEAR=(T2.YEAR-1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the query. I have a quick question. Why it is T2.Year-1? If I have 2014 and 2016 for comparing, will it work same way?

Comment: If you are sure that there is only 2 years for each item, 2014 and (2015 or 2016), then you can use this condition `(T1.YEAR < T2.YEAR)`. These things should be deducible from the answer.

Comment: What if instead of Numeric value in Year, if I have Nov2015 ( in lieu of 2014) and Dec2015 ( in lieu of 2015), will it still work? Sorry, I am trying to learn here

Comment: Parse it using string. But that would be a total different question from the one you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Using the lag function is the best approach to this.

```
SELECT  [Year], [Item], [Qty], [Amount],
       [Qty] - LAG([Qty]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Item] ORDER BY [Year]) [QtyDiff],
       [Amount] - LAG([Amount]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Item] ORDER BY [Year]) [AmountDiff]
FROM [ItemTable] it
order BY [Year] DESC, [Item];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the required query:

```
SET @YEAR1 = '2014';
SET @YEAR2 = '2015';

SELECT 
      Item,
      if(count(*)>1,sum(if(Year=@YEAR2,Qty,-Qty)),NULL) as 'Qty Diff',                                 
      if(count(*)>1,sum(if(Year=@YEAR2,Amount,-Amount)),NULL) as 'Amount Diff' 
FROM 
      table 
WHERE 
      Year IN (@YEAR1,@YEAR2) 
group by Item;
```